# Как проверить есть ли в строке цифры или какие-либо спецсимволы?

Tags: python, django

Я делаю систему регистрации на сайте, и мне нужно проверить, валидно ли имя(Оно содержит только буквы).
Здесь моя первая и неудачная попытка это реализовать. По-любому есть более легкий метод и мне не надо было изобретать велосипед. Помогите...

Вьюха:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import registrationForm




def auth(request):
    return render(request, 'access/auth.html')


def reg(request):
    # Ошибки
    name_error = ''
    email_error = ''
    len_pass_error = ''
    pass_error = ''

    # Список символов в имени/фамилии

    name_surname = ['а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р',
    'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
    'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = registrationForm(request.POST)
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        second_name = request.POST.get('second_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
        date_of_birht = request.POST.get('date_of_birht')
        if password == password2:
            if len(password) >= 8:
                if '@' in email:

                    first_name.lower()

                    for i in range(len(first_name)):
                        if first_name[i-1] in name_surname:
                            first_name.replace(first_name[i-1], '1')
                        else:
                            first_name.replace(first_name[i-1], '0')

                    if not '0' in first_name:                                   
                        form.save()
                        return redirect('/')                        
                    else:
                        name_error = 'Недействительное имя'
                else:   
                    email_error = 'Недействительный адрес электронной почты'    
                
            else:
                len_pass_error = 'Пароль слишком короткий'
                
        else:
            pass_error = 'Пароли не совпадают'


        

            


    form = registrationForm()
    context = {
        'form' : form,
        'pass_error' : pass_error,
        'len_pass_error' : len_pass_error,  
        'email_error' : email_error,    
        'name_error' : name_error,
    }
    return render(request, 'access/reg.html', context)
```

Comment: Для этой задачи подходят регулярные выражения. [Модуль для питона](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: можно конкретнее?

Comment: Если нужны только буквы, то проверить имя на `^\w+$` просто.

Comment: `name_surname = ['а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р',
    'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
    'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']` пример как ненужно делать. Гугли regexp для питона. Если не зайдут, то как вариант (не рекомендую) ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

```
if not all(map(str.isalpha, first_name)):
    name_error = 'Недействительное имя'
```